# Invert string breaking by characters in C#

Tags: c#, string

How do I make this string reverse?

Let's suppose I have

```
11 <- 6 <- 5 <- 1 <- 0
```

I want it to turn into

```
0 -> 1 -> 5 -> 6 -> 11
```

Should I use Split? Or what?

Edit: I can change `<-` to `;` without problems, if it make it easier.

Comment: I'd split it into an array then use `Array.Reverse`... Seems simple, have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm trying with `var reversedStr = string.Join("->", ordem.Split(';').Reverse());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First split the string by the `->` sequence and trim the excess white space, then reverse the array and use `string.Join` to add the arrows between the numbers.

```
var split = string.Join(" -> ",
                str.Split(new[] {"<-"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Select(x => x.Trim()).Reverse()).Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Verbose answer:

```
        string strIn = "11 <- 6 <- 5 <- 1 <- 0";
        Console.WriteLine(strIn);

        string[] values = strIn.Split(" <-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Array.Reverse(values);
        string strOut = string.Join(" -> ", values);

        Console.WriteLine(strOut);
```

Comment: this was the fastest one.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq . Just Reverse string and Replace `<` with `>`.

```
string strRev = string.Join("", str.Reverse()).Replace('<', '>');
```

Comment: Oops. yes i didnt notice that. so the only way is to split. @PhiterFernandes